# Is there a way in Google Sheets to combine JOINs and FILTERs in a dynamic way and with one single formula?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, filtering

I have a situation like the one depicted in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]
In column `E:E` there's a list of words that I want to join.
In column `F:F` there's a sequence of increasing integers.
In cell `G5` theres an integer (1999) that divides the previous increasing list of integers in several groups (1, 2, 3 ,4 etc). The groups show up below 1999, in range `G6:G`.
In colum `H:H` I have the desired results, which by now I am able to achieve via a series of JOINS and FILTERS placed manually in each cell under `H6`. In the first row (cell `H6`), we find words joined that belong to the group 1, in the cell below words belonging to group 2 and so on.
I would like to achieve the same results but with one single formula, located in cell `H6`, a formula that would work independently of how long the list of words is, or how large the interger divider is, or how many resulting groups are.
Thank you so much.

[Spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x2tna7bMu1EQHDu5zrwpxLkcYm1xRHtLii59fpP-vEI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating everything directly from your lists of words and integers, and the divisor value (so avoiding the need for columns G & I):

```
=arrayformula(let(
integers,tocol(F6:F,1),
words,tocol(E6:E,1),
divisor,$G$5,
groups,ceiling(integers/divisor,1),
map(unique(groups),lambda(each,join(", ",filter(words,groups=each))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAP`, like this:

```
=MAP(I6:I,LAMBDA(i,iferror(if(i="",,join(", ",filter( E:E,G:G=i))),)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the intention was not to use the column I:I for the purpose of the excercise